# Beautiful Soup Access the second <div with the same class

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping an html document that contains two 'hooks' of the same class like below:

```
<div class="multiRow">
    <!--ModuleId 372329FileName @swMultiRowsContainer-->
    <some more content>
</div>
<div class="multiRow">
    <!--ModuleId 372330FileName @multiRowsContainer-->
    <some more content>
</div>
```

When I do:

```
mr = ct[0].find_all('div', {'class': 'multiRow'})
```

I only get contents from the first 
Is there a way to get access to contents within the second  ?

Thanks!

Comment: find_all should return an iterator of all the different ones. have you tried casting it to a list and accessing the second element?

Comment: @sihrc in BeautifulSoup 4, `find_all` returns a `ResultSet` object which is accessibly by index, so casting it to `list` wouldn't even be necessary.

Comment: @AdamSmith Ah yes, you're right. My mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit with Adam Smith's comment.

Refer to my comment above, code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
a = "<div class=\"multiRow\"><!--ModuleId 372329FileName @swMultiRowsContainer-->Bye</div>    <div class=\"multiRow\"><!--ModuleId 372330FileName @multiRowsContainer-->Hi</div>"

print soup(a).find_all("div",{"class":"multiRow"})[1]
```

returns:

```
<div class="multiRow"><!--ModuleId 372330FileName @multiRowsContainer-->Hi</div>
```

Comment: $sihrc, this works. But I found out that the problem is different. I'll have to post another question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Coding example for **Adam Smith's** comment. I think it is very clear.

```
ct= soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "multiRow"})
ct= ct[1]
print(ct)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are asking for the first content only, check your code

```
ct[0].find_all
```

The `ct[0]` will grab only the first content, not the whole. Fix that.